# An occasional error with BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, bufferedreader

I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I invoke this function, but not always. Out of **10 attempts**, I got an error **3 times**, and the remaining **7 times** it worked perfectly fine.

```
void readTrainingData(Model m) throws FileNotFoundException  {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("training_data.csv"));
    } catch (IOException ex)    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    String line = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)    {
            String[] coords = line.split(",");
            if (coords[0] != null && coords[1] != null) {
                m.x[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[0]);
                m.y[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[1]);
            }
            else    {
                System.out.println("Check training_data.csv");
            }

            j = 0;
            i++;
        }        
    } catch (IOException ex)    {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file");
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

The error is as follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at polygonprobability.Util.readTrainingData(Util.java:215)
```

I can't debug it because whenever I'm trying to, I don't get the error.

I'm thoroughly confused. Please help.

EDIT : I changed the conditional to

```
if (coords[0] != null && coords[1] != null && coords.length == 2)   {
         m.x[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[0]);
     m.y[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[1]);
}
```

Line 215 happens to be the if conditional itself.

Even after the change, the error persists.

Comment: Which line is the 215th?

Comment: Try to change `if (coords[0] != null && coords[1] != null) {` to `if (coords.length == 2) {`

Comment: You can have a check in your if condition for size of the array coords.size>=2 && do your validation

Comment: @wrahool Your condition is not good , check my answer , how it should be formed.

Answer (score 2):

Do this changes

```
    if (coords.length == 2 && coords[0] != null && coords[1] != null )   {
             m.x[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[0]);
         m.y[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[1]);
    }
```

Comment: I did it. No change though. :(

Comment: Give me line where you are getting new exception

Comment: you applied the change wrongly, `coords.length == 2` must be the first check inside the if

Answer (score 1):

> I get an Array IndexOutOfBoundsException when I invoke this function, but not always. Out of 10 attempts, I got an error 3 times, and the remaining 7 times it worked perfectly fine.

First potential danger :

```
if (coords[0] != null && coords[1] != null)
```

Here you are assuming `coords` array will always have `2` elements .

**Change your condition to :**

```
 // check for coords.length == 2 first inside the if 
 // if the first condition fails , others won't be evaluated for short circuit AND
 if ( coords.length == 2 && coords[0] != null && coords[1] != null)   {
     m.x[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[0]);
     m.y[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[1]);
}
```

Second ,

```
m.x[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[0]);
m.y[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[1]);
```

Your `x` and `y` may not contain the index valued by `i`.

Show us your `Model` class , specifically the attributes `x` and `y` and how do you intialise them.

Answer (score 1):

[**IndexOutOfBoundsException**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.

In your case i think following line of code is making problem,

```
 String[] coords = line.split(",");
```

**you should check it's length `coords.length` before accessing it.**

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that you will always have an array of at least two elements in `coords`, add some code to validate that you are indeed getting an array of at least two elements.

Change your if statement to:

```
if (coords.length >= 2) {
    m.x[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[0]);
    m.y[i] = Float.parseFloat(coords[1]);
}
```

Comment: change the if statement to validate the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

First check the length of the `coords` array then move forward as

```
if(coords.lenght()>=2) {
  //here parse your float
}
```

it is due to the unchecked length, you are assuming that `coords` length will be of 2 always.